# How come it doesn't slice a number until the end despite including the number's length

Tags: javascript

I made a code to extract every odd numbers from one number, and it works for numbers that are not too long such as "1341" (which give me the numbers "1,13,1341,341,41,1") but oddly doesn't work for very long numbers.

```
function solve(s) {
    var newarray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <= s.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j <= s.length; j++) {
            var slicing = s.slice(i, j);
            if (slicing % 2 !== 0) {
                newarray.push(slicing);
            }
        }
    }
    return newarray.length;
}
```

Despite putting s.length, it slices until a certain point. For example:

With "93711892377292643581488317", it slices until "9371189237729", then when it starts from 3 it slices until "93711892377292643" (until the next odd number)

With "65266112954758467", from the start it slices until "6526611295475", then when it starts from 5, it slices until "65266112954758467" (until the next odd number).

What's going on?

Comment: The calls to `.slice()` change the length of the string, so your indexes are thrown off. If you used `.substr()` instead to just make a copy of a region of the string, that wouldn't happen. Also starting `j` at 0 doesn't make sense.

Comment: Pardon me, but could you be more specific, I've begun coding since a few months ago, so I'm no expert.
I switched from .slice() to substr() but there's no difference.
Could you tell me please why .slice changes the length of the string, and why J at 0 doesn't make sense? What confuses me the most is the fact that it works for a short number.

Is there a correction I can make in this code, or do I have to cancel it?

Answer (score 0):

`slicing % 2` doesn't work properly when `slicing` is large. Javascript treats large numbers as floating-point numbers, which means it's not accurate to know the value to the nearest integer - in binary, the units bit becomes 0, so it's a multiple of 2.

Answer (score 0):

You want to count all odd numeric substrings within a numeric string.

First, consult the documentation of [str.slice(beginIndex[, endIndex])](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice).

Then, in order to gain a better understanding of your code, it is helpful to slowly iterate through a few steps of your loops and write down the expected vs. the observed output.

I recommend to use the debugger built into all modern browsers:

1. Add a `debugger;` statement into the inner for-loop:

   ```
   function solve(s) {
     var newarray = [];
     for (var i = 0; i <= s.length; i++) {
       for (var j = 0; j <= s.length; j++) {
         var slicing = s.slice(i, j);
         debugger; // <-- we want to break here and check our values

         if (slicing % 2 !== 0) {
           newarray.push(slicing);
         }
       }
     }
     return newarray.length;
   }
   ```
2. Press [F12] and run this code in your browser's console for some exemplary input.
3. The debugger tab should now pop up. Press [F8] to step through your code and keep track of the value of your `slicing` variable.

You will probably notice that `slicing` is empty at the beginning. You should start your inner loop from `j = i + 1` to fix that.

Also, you might notice that your `i` iterates one time too many, so that `slicing` is empty during the final iterations of the inner for-loop. You need to terminate your outer loop one step earlier.

Then, for the problematic input `"93711892377292643581488317"` you will notice that large numeric slices such as `"93711892377292643"` will not be recognized as odd.  `"93711892377292643" % 2` evaluates to `0` instead of `1`. In order to understand this, you need to know that JavaScript numbers are internally represented as limited precision floating point values. If you put `93711892377292643` into your browser console, it will evaluate to `93711892377292640` - an even number! JavaScript can only handle integer numbers up to `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER == 9007199254740991` without introducing such truncation errors.

Now, how to solve this issue? Well, a number is odd if and only if the last digit is odd. So we don't have to inspect the full number, just the last digit:

```js
function solve(s) {
  var newarray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    for (var j = i; j < s.length; j++) {
      var digit = s.slice(j, j + 1);
      if (digit % 2 !== 0) {
        var slicing = s.slice(i, j + 1);
        newarray.push(slicing);
      }
    }
  }
  return newarray.length;
}

console.log(solve("1234567890")); // 25
```

Once you have sufficient understanding of this code, you could start improving it. You could for example replace the `newarray` with a simple counter, as you are only interested in the number of off digits, not the digits themselves.

A faster solution could be written down as follows:

```js
function solve(str) {
  let count = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] % 2) count += i + 1;
  }
  return count;
}

console.log(solve("1234567890")); // 25
```

Or, written in a more declarative way:

```js
const solve = (str) =>
  str.split('').reduce((count, chr, i) => chr % 2 ? count + i + 1 : count, 0);

console.log(solve("1234567890")); // 25
```

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to get every possible odd numbers (not digit). With "1234567890", it should give me "1,123,12345,1234567,123456789,3,345,34567,3456789,5,567,56789,7,789,9"

Comment: Yes, indeed I forgot those odd numbers

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll take time to try understand it.